# htaccess redirect in subdomain causes address issue

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

## Prelude

As shown in the picture below, there is a problem in the `.htaccess` code that follows (after the picture).

[image: screenshot]

## The code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ .anon.php [L]
```

## The Purpose

What I'm trying to do here is to have only an `.htaccess` file and a `.anon.php` file that can be used either in `document root` -or inside a sub-folder where the sub-domain resides; however, all requests must be directed at the `.anon.php` file.

## The Issue

The above redirect rules work very well, but for some reason ***when a folder exists*** -then it prepends the current subdirectory (sub-domain's folder) to the request.

> The code above does not cause that redirect-loop as seen; the loop comes from some PHP code that I wrote to try and mitigate this issue, because: when you manually change the address in the address bar (after it redirected wrong the first time) -then all subsequent requests/refreshes work fine - 100%

I had to clear all browsing data/cache in order to re-produce this issue.
The redirect-loop as explained does not happen in chromium-based browsers such as **Brave Chrome Opera** .. strange but true.

## The Solution

The only issue is that it prepends the existing sub-domain's folder to the address in the redirect -only if the requested folder exists. The solution would be to instruct the rules to ... "not do that" -but I don't know how, been at this for 2 days now and I know the solution should be fairly simple.

I've found many "sub-domain-as-root" examples, but none of them fixes this exact issue.
Any answers and comments would be appreciated -and rewarded, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

this maybe can help you

```
 RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?PUTYOURDOMAINNAMEHERE.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/PUTYOURFOLDERHERE/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /PUTYOURFOLDERHERE/$1  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?PUTYOURDOMAINNAMEHERE.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ PUTYOURFOLDERHERE/ [L]
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```